# dynamic mapping in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a `.txt` file which contains the data in `json` format. I would like to create mapping by using the below method, but it is showing an exception:

> Root type mapping not empty after parsing (while creating mapping with dynamic template).

I would be thankful to you if you tell me what is the mistake and how to resolve it.

```
InputStream fileStream;
StringBuilder mapTemplate= new StringBuilder();
String line;
File mapFile = new File(mapFileBase);  //mapFileBase is a string which holds the path name of the .txt file
fileStream = new FileInputStream(mapFile);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new inputStreamReader(fileStream));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    mapTemplate.append(line);
}
String mTemplate=mapTemplate.toString();
mTemplate=mTemplate.replaceAll("\n ", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "");
System.out.println(mTemplate);
createIndexRequestBuilder.addMapping(type, mappingBuilder);

// MAPPING DONE

createIndexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

And I can't use

```
 XContentBuilder mappingBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                .startObject(type)
                .startObject("properties")..........
```

as the json file is very huge.

Comment: Please post the contents of mTemplate

Comment: The data is bit confidential. Are there any possibilities of error in that json file?

Comment: Yes, please sanatize the file and then post it

Comment: :) not sure if there's anything in the dynamic mapping template that can be used to hack your ES servers, take control and beat the entire world into submission.

Comment: Yes, quite possibly the mapping JSON isn't correct, recently ES has gotten very strict with the mapping definitions. Which is why we are asking to see the mapping.